# How to pass arguments to a pre-built docker image through docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ganache

I want to pass some arguments to a prebuilt docker image through the compose file. So, I don't have the Dockerfile and I can't use the context.

For instance, in the docker hub documentation of the ganache-cli image, there is the possibility to use the following command to run

```
docker run --detach --publish 8545:8545 trufflesuite/ganache-cli:latest --accounts 10 --debug
```

The question is, how to pass this accounts 10 through the docker compose file?

So far I have

```
ganache:
  network_mode: 'host'
  image: "trufflesuite/ganache-cli:latest"
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with `ganache` but here: https://github.com/digitaldonkey/ganache-cli-docker-compose/blob/master/docker-compose.yml `--deterministic` option was passed from `entrypoint`. Maybe the same might apply to `--accounts`.

Comment: Alternative approach to @doneforaiur mentioned is to use command (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#command) and then execute it that way. (same goes for me, i do not know anything about ganache).

Comment: @matic1123 that's neater!

Comment: Both solutions perfectly work. Thanks! But I prefer the command one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever is used after the image name in a `docker run` command replaces any `CMD` statement in the image and is passed to the entrypoint as parameters - or, if there is no entrypoint - just run as a command.

To have the equivalent of your `docker run` command in a docker-compose file, you'd create something like this:

```
ganache:
  image: trufflesuite/ganache-cli:latest
  command: --accounts 10 --debug
  ports:
    - 8545:8545
```

Then you'd run it using `docker compose up -d` or `docker-compose up -d` depending on the version of compose you have installed.